# Oracle XMLTable how to extract a field from this XML

Tags: xml, oracle, soap

I am trying to extract a field from the following XML with Oracle:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns2:check xmlns:ns2="http://soap.com" xmlns="http://soap.com/xsd">
      <ns2:request>
        <orderIDs>201902281425597269</orderIDs>
      </ns2:request>
    </ns2:check>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried the following and variations of it, but no luck:

```
..
    XMLTable(XMLNAMESPACES (
      'http://soap.com/xsd' AS "ns2"
    ),
    'for $i in //orderIDs return $i'
    passing XMLType(sm.REQUEST_XML)
    columns "ORDER_ID" VARCHAR2(500) path '/') xt_orderid
..
```

The above is part of a query where it is cross-joined with other table. What doesn't work is that the query returns no results, so I guess the XMLTable command turns up empty.

A very similar extraction command works for the response, but the response is structured differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `ns2` using the wrong path, but you don't refer to it anyway; as `orderIds` doesn't have a namespace prefix you need to declare a default instead (or as well):

```
XMLTable(XMLNAMESPACES (
  default 'http://soap.com/xsd', 'http://soap.com' AS "ns2"
),
'for $i in //orderIDs return $i'
passing XMLType(sm.REQUEST_XML)
columns "ORDER_ID" VARCHAR2(500) path '/') xt_orderid
```

You don't need the `for` here either, you can use a simpler path; demo with your sample data in a CTE:

```
with sm (request_xml) as (
  select '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns2:check xmlns:ns2="http://soap.com" xmlns="http://soap.com/xsd">
      <ns2:request>
        <orderIDs>201902281425597269</orderIDs>
      </ns2:request>
    </ns2:check>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>' from dual
)
select xt_orderid.order_id
from sm
cross join
    XMLTable(XMLNAMESPACES (
      default 'http://soap.com/xsd'
    ),
    '//orderIDs'
    passing XMLType(sm.REQUEST_XML)
    columns "ORDER_ID" VARCHAR2(500) path '/') xt_orderid
/

ORDER_ID                                          
--------------------------------------------------
201902281425597269
```

You could also wildcard the namespace but that's not ideal, and generally I'd prefer to give the full path (with appropriate namespace for each node) if it's static. And if your XML will only have that one order ID you could use XMLQuery instead of XMLTable, but I imagine you're really going to be pulling out other information from a larger document.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Poole, it appears my default namespace was wrong. It works now.